# How do you do a Healthcheck for Fluentd's Default ports?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fluentd, health-check

I was looking through docker hub, etc and generally I can find a mechanism to look up healthchecks for different containers.   I didnt see any for FluentD though.

I would like to essentially do a curl from the container to confirm it is healthy.

My issue is that i have underlying containers which will start immediately but fail because 24224 on fluentd is not available.

So what I thought to do was to write similar to:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  fluentd:
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
      - "24224:24224/udp"
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:24224 || exit 1
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
  sample:
    depends_on:
      fluentd:
        condition: container_healthy
```

In this sample test, It seems that the Curl command I set up was not the correct command to validate the health of fluentd.

I did not seem to find anything specific to this from my searches, but maybe others might know what to do.

My error was: `Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: dial tcp [::1]:24224: connect: connection refused` when it attempts to set up logging to fluentd.

Comment: I dont know if this is the right answer, but by default for the fluentd logging driver, it will attempt to validate it first.   If you add to the options: `fluentd-async: "true"` it seems to bypass that check and all the containers seem to then work.